# GitHub Copilot - Strange Injection of characters with Visual Studio - Javascript AND C#

Tags: javascript, c#, github-copilot

I was using Visual Studio for an ASP.netcore project at work with Github Copilot. I was writing javascript in one of the Views. A strange thing happened where lowercase d's were injected into the code at random times and random places.

In the editor, there were characters that were being inject in places in the source causing errors, and either I had to undo the insertion of the characters or delete them. Yet, when I would add more code to the source, the characters would be inserted again. This proved to be difficult to debug as it kept happening.

This was also happening with C# in a DotNet 7 project. It was a hard time to clean up and I had to turn off Copilot. There were a couple curly braces that were injected, also.

This is peculiar behavior. What is happening here?

Comment: I asked the question in February and found the answer.

Comment: Your question would be better if you more accurately characterized the behaviour.  I realize some things appear at "random times and random places" but do your best to either help people reproduce the problem, or at least describe what you did to elicit the behaviour.  And most importantly, when it's flakey randomness, collect good evidence of the behaviour so that other people can compare their results to yours.  "lowercase d's injected at random times and random places" is a sketchy account of what you actually observed and what you did to cause it.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the issue with this was that I was using the Vim extension in Visual Studio. Because I had been using Vim commands, GitHub Copilot was getting very confused.

I hope this helps someone having the same behavior to save some time. It was very confusing, and it took me a long time to make the connection. You would think that GitHub Copilot would not take the time to learn Vim. It is hard enough for a human to learn it.

I have not had other issues with GitHub Copilot and prompt programming has become very useful. I just hope they iron out these kind of kinks in the future versions. I would love to be able to continue using Vim.

Comment: Please consider if this is something that may be useful for the public - or this was a particular mistake you made. In the latter is the case, consider deleting the question.